# Getting 406 Not Acceptable when Ktor serializes the object

Tags: kotlin, ktor, http-status-code-406, klaxon

Why am I getting `406 Not Acceptable` when I return the ApiResponse (the commented out line) and let Ktor serialize it vs doing the in-code Klaxon serialization directly?

```
    route("/hello") {
        get {
            println("hello there...")
            println("Hello, ${call.principal<JWTPrincipal>()?.subject}!")

            call.respond(Klaxon().toJsonString(ApiResponse(body = "Nothing found")))
//            call.respond(ApiResponse(body = "Nothing found"))

        }
```

ApiResponse:

```
import kotlinx.serialization.Contextual
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class ApiResponse(
    val error: Boolean? = false,
    val errorMessage: String? = null,
    @Contextual
    val body: Any? = null
)
```

Comment: If I run your code as is, the `Serializer for class 'Any' is not found` error occurs. If I replace the `Any` type with `T` type, everything works fine.

Comment: That worked! Please post the answer and I'll accept. Although I still don't get why Any wouldn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Any` type isn't serializable so you need to replace `Any` with the generic type:

```
@Serializable
data class ApiResponse<T>(
    val error: Boolean? = false,
    val errorMessage: String? = null,
    @Contextual
    val body: T? = null
)
```